# Cutting a string from 0 to a word

Tags: php

How can I cut the following string:

```
http://www.example.com/brand=1&maxprice=300&page=2
```

To this string:

```
http://www.example.com/brand=1&maxprice=300&
```

In other words, how can I cut a string until a certain word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier way, but use `strpos` to find the index where the word occurs, then use `substr` using `0`, and the index that `strpos` found.

```
$myString = "http://www.example.com/brand=1&maxprice=300&page=2"

$newString = substr($myString,0,strpos($myString, "page"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will help.

```
<?php
$str="http://www.example.com/brand=1&maxprice=300&page=2";

$str=explode('&',$str);
var_dump($str);
echo $str[0].'&'.$str[1].'&'; //http://www.example.com/brand=1&maxprice=300&
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string='http://www.example.com/brand=1&maxprice=300&page=2';
$string=substr($string,0,strpos($string,'page'));
echo $string;  // echo 'http://www.example.com/brand=1&maxprice=300&'
```

This will echo everything from index `0` to the word `page`.